Any way to use Xbox Controller without timer in Wpf
I am using SharpDX.XInput in order to detect controller and get information from it.
I basically use timer and check the state of my controller in each tick.
The problem is that it is not consistent enough. Sometimes I press to right button and it works and sometimes does not work. (Although I make my timer interval 1 microsecond which is the lowest interval)
My code is like this.
public static Controller Controller { get; set; }
public static State ControllerState { get; set; }

Controller = new Controller(UserIndex.One);

if (Controller.IsConnected == false)
return;

_deviceType = SharpDX.DirectInput.DeviceType.Gamepad;

_dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
_dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1);

_dispatcherTimer.Start();

 private static async void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await TimerTick(_deviceType);
}

private static async Task TimerTick(SharpDX.DirectInput.DeviceType deviceType)
{
  try
  {

      ControllerState = Controller.GetState();

      _stateY = ControllerState.Gamepad.LeftThumbY;
      _stateX = ControllerState.Gamepad.LeftThumbX;
      _gamepadButtonFlags = ControllerState.Gamepad.Buttons.ToString();
      if (_gamepadButtonFlags == "None")
      {
          HandleDPadButtons(true);
          HandleDirections(true);
          HandleDirectionCount(0);
          return;

      }

      switch (_gamepadButtonFlags)
      {
          case "DPadRight":
              Right();
              break;
          case "DPadUp":
              Up();
              break;
          case "DPadLeft":
              Left();
              break;
          case "DPadDown":
              Down();
              break;
          case "A":
              PressA();
              break;
          case "B":
              PressB();
              break;
          case "X":
              PressX();
              break;
          case "Y":
              PressY();
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }


      if (!_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("A") &&
          !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("B") &&
          !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("X") &&
          !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("Y"))
      {
          HandleDPadButtons(true);
      }

      if (!_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("DPadRight") &&
       !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("DPadUp") &&
       !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("DPadLeft") &&
       !_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains("DPadDown"))
      {
          HandleDirections(true);
          HandleDirectionCount(0);
      }

  }
  catch (SharpDXException sharpDXException)
  {
      _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
      _buttonTimer.Stop();
      MessageController.ShowMessage("Controller lost!", "Error on joystick timer.", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }
 }

I'd appreciate any help/suggestion in order to use xbox controller as consistent as any other desktop pc games in WPF.

I'm not sure, but I think there should be an EventHandler when something has changed.

At least your way to check GamepadButtonFlags value is inefficient. Why don't you use Enum.HasFrag method?

I don't know how to use them. Should I compare like
if (_gamepadButtonFlags.Contains( 0x0001))  ?

You certainly don't want to do something on he dispatcher thread every tick...
